# How to embed i-jetty server into android application?

Tags: java, android, jetty, embedded-jetty, ijetty

Hi: I want to integrate i-jetty into an Android application and not the other way around. Has anyone included i-jetty before and got it to run under Android 2.1 or 2.2?

Comment: I need the same thing, did you manage to do this yet?

Comment: Same for me, has anyone managed to integrate i-jetty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I successfully managed to integrate I-Jetty into my application, for anyone out there who is still hoping to do so.

So basically what I did is I downloaded the i-jetty source code and imported it as a maven project in eclipse. Then I added a module to the parent pom.xml that points to a webapp maven module I made:

```
<modules>
   <module>i-jetty-server</module>
   <module>i-jetty-ui</module>
   <module>webapp</module>
</modules>
```

and listed the i-jetty-parent as the parent in the webapp module's pom.xml:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.ijetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>ijetty-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Then I copied all my android application files into the i-jetty-ui maven module (including all source files and resources). Then you just change the i-jetty AndroidManifest.xml file to include all your new activities and change the 'startup' activity to your own application's launch activity, and remove the

```
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
```

from the IJetty activity declaration.

And thus you have the original i-jetty application running within your own!
Let me know if you need more details, I assumed here you have looked into the source code and have a basic understanding of maven.

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that your Question is still Unanswered for this long time and and so I tried to Answer it.[**`This link`**](http://puregeekjoy.blogspot.in/2011/06/running-embedded-jetty-in-android-app.html) would help you to get started off in integrating the **`i-jetty`** server in your App.

Comment: This is actually is about embedding jetty, not i-jetty, into an android application.