# Embedded HTTP Server for Android

Tags: android, embeddedwebserver

I am looking for a embedded HTTP server for an android device.The HTTP server needs to be a library,so that I can customize the responses(I would be doing some native operations on the device like switching on wifi etc... according to the request fired and fire back the response).For iOS we have CocoaHttpServer which is capable of doing such thing.

I saw there is NanoHTTPD,but am looking at some other options as well before finalizing anything.

Comment: You should have a look at i-jetty (https://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/). It offers full embeddable java web server and access to native android API.

Comment: I am looking more of a webserver as part of my application where I can create custom responses rather than the other way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032426/how-to-embed-i-jetty-server-into-android-application see how people managed to embed iJetty into an Android App. Perhaps the original Jetty Server is ment to be embeddable in Java apps (not android) out of the box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android embedded web-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964535/android-embedded-web-server)

Answer (score 1):

[SIMPLE](http://www.simpleframework.org/index.php) is embedded HTTP server which provides a Java library. SIMPLE can be regarded as another option of NanoHTTPD. SIMPLE is exactly one of some other options you are looking for.

The goal of Simple is to bring the power of simplicity to the world of server side Java. The primary focus of the project is to provide a truly embeddable Java based HTTP engine capable of handling enormous loads.